# Linking URLs in tweets passed through Feedzirra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, feedzirra

I'm working on a rails website that's using Feedzirra to bring in a rotating twitter feed.  The tweets, however, aren't bringing clickable URLs - just an unlinked string.

Is there a "rails way" to link the URLs as they come through Feedzirra, before they are displayed?  Or do I need to use something post-parse (like jQuery) to take care of it?

EDIT:

feed.rb - http://pastebin.com/0eSEGYZq

actual tweets - http://pastebin.com/KUMGZF4X

Comment: Share some code of how have you done it?

Comment: just edited to show feed.rb and the actual tweet code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you loop through the results you could try using this gem: https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink

Comment: Works great.  Passed tweet.title into as follows: 

<% auto_link(tweet.title)%>

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that Twitter is shutting off their RSS feeds permanently in the very near future.